# Can we access iphone Images ,Audios and Videos Programiticaly for upload to Server?

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, mono

hi i want to get all videos, audios and images in iphone and upload them to server can we perform this task programitically is it possible in iphone sdk ?

Comment: See this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282830/uiimagepickercontroller-uiimage-memory-and-more

Answer (score 0):

Starting from iOS 4, you can use ALAssetsLibrary to retrieve images and videos: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

edit: the whole framework api can be found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009730